# "You are not authorized to access this page." in Chrome after returning from offsite payment

Tags: 8, commerce

After concluding checkout flow on site I'm redirected to offsite payment service (Datatrans).
There if I finish payment and I get redirected back to:

/checkout/order_number/payment/return

or I cancel payment and get redirected back to:

/checkout/order_number/payment/cancel

on site I get the message:

***You are not authorized to access this page.***

At that point I'm not logged out - if I just reload the page (click on browser address bar and hit enter to open page again. I get redirected to:

/checkout/order_number/order_information

Important - this happens only **in Google Chrome**. In Firefox this works well.

Comment: Did you test with an incognito window?

Comment: No, standard way. I'm logged in regularly. And as far as I could see in Firefox it works well, but Chrome is having this issue.

Comment: You need to check in Incognito to rule out browser plugins

Comment: Tried incognito mode and it also happens. On FF I get redirected to order information page with message "You have canceled checkout at Datatrans but may resume the checkout process here when you are ready. ", but on Chrome (even in incognito mode)  I stay on checkout/order_id/payment/cancel with message "You are not authorized to access this page.", and if I refresh the page then I'm redirected to order information with proper message.

Comment: Just saw that I had some Google Chrome update pending so after updating it in Incognito mode it works ok. I guess there was some bug in Chrome then?

Comment: Check in other chromium based browsers. It could be a chrome bug or chromium. Try Brave, newest version of Edge etc

Comment: I posted a solution provided by person more experienced then me with server configuration and network communication. I would like to hear your opinion on that solution.

Comment: Having the same issue here with Commerce Datatrans module. Nothing that I have tried so far worked for me, incl. your solution. I always end up with a 403 / Forbidden on `checkout/order_number/payment/return` path. I am on latest Chrome (86) and the same happens with Brave, Safari and Firefox except that on Safari and Firefox I get a browser alert about the unsafe POST back to D8 before the 403. The message (translated from French) is something like *This form will be sent in an unsafe way. Do you really want to send it?*. In all cases, Commerce then thinks there was an issue with the payment.

Comment: Updated my answer bellow with a link I get from Datatrans tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be adding following rows to .htaccess file inside `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` block.

```
  Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=None; Secure"
  Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=None; Secure"
```

Some more info on this issue:

https://docs.datatrans.ch/v1.0.1/docs/security-samesite-cookies